# sort: read failed: ./folder/: Is a directory

Tags: disk-usage, sort, read

When I run:

```
du -sh ./*/
```

I get the following error:

> ```
> sort: read failed: ./folder/: Is a directory
> ```

How do I fix this?

Is there something wrong with `sort` on my system. 
I am running `x86_64 Linux 4.16.8-1-ARCH`.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there were provided too little information and therefore could be classified as unclear, but I post this comment in order to clarify for a seemingly new SE user.

Comment: Is `du` an alias or function on your system? Check with `type du`.  I'm guessing that its either an alias or a function that calls `sort` and that it does it incorrectly.

Comment: @Kusalananda Thank you, that was it! It was an alias.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `du` utility will never produce that error message.  The message comes from `sort`.  The `sort` utility produces that message when given a command line argument that is a folder when it expects a file.

Therefore, it is reasonable to assume that `du` is in fact a shell function or an alias that calls `sort` in such a way that `sort` is given a directory name as command line argument when the alias/function is called in the way it is called in the question. The alias or function is in other words buggy.

That `du` was an alias was later confirmed by the original user in comments.